# cmd command is not recognized as > an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c#, cmd

when i run this code.

```
public void WaterMarkingUsingCommandLine(string videopath, string imagepath)
{
    string OutputFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Output\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(videopath) + "_Output.mp4";
    string ffmpegPath = @""""+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"ffmpeg.exe""";
    string ffmpegParams = @"-i """+videopath+@""" -i """+imagepath+@""" -filter_complex ""overlay=10:10"" """+OutputFolder+@"""";

    Process ffmpeg = new Process();
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k " + ffmpegPath + " " + ffmpegParams;
    ffmpeg.Start();
}
```

I see this in cmd.

> 'c:\users\jafar.baltidynamolog\documents\visual' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\jafar.baltidynamolog\Videos\videos>

The problem seems to be due to space.As told in other questions, I have added commas around the filenames but still it is not working.

**Update**

By Debugging i found that value of

ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments=

> "/k \"c:\users\jafar.baltidynamolog\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\VideoProjectBilal\VideoProjectBilal\bin\Debug\ffmpeg.exe\"
>   -i \"C:\Users\jafar.baltidynamolog\Videos\videos\SampleVideo_360x240_2mb.mp4\"
>   -i \"C:\Users\jafar.baltidynamolog\Videos\images\2.png\" -filter_complex \"overlay=10:10\" \"c:\users\jafar.baltidynamolog\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\VideoProjectBilal\VideoProjectBilal\bin\Debug\Output\SampleVideo_360x240_2mb_Output.mp4\""

Comment: please share what you get in `ffmpegPath` and `ffmpedParams`. You may have to wrap `ffmpegPath` in double quotes.

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but there's probably no need to launch via `cmd /k` - your `StartInfo`'s filename should be the path to ffmpeg.exe, and the arguments should be altered accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:
`string ffmpegPath = @""""+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"ffmpeg.exe""";` 

for this:
 `string ffmpegPath = @"""" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ffmpeg.exe";`

**Update**

Try this:

```
string OutputFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Output\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(videopath) + "_Output.mp4";
string ffmpegPath =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ffmpeg.exe";
string ffmpegParams = "-i " + videopath + " -i " + imagepath + " -filter_complex overlay=10:10 " + OutputFolder ;
```